# Why the bodyParser.json was used twice?

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I am a beginner of Node.js , I am researching the sample code as below, I do not understandard why it using the [app.use(bodyParser.json());] twice, what is the purpose of #1 and #2? thanks

```
    var express = require('express');
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var mime = require('mime');

    var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var cfenv = require('cfenv');

    var vcapServices = require('vcap_services');
    var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv(); 

    var app = express(); 
    app.use(cookieParser()); 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // #1
    app.set('appName', 'watsonDemo');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 6003);

    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/HTML'));
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/HTML'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // #2

    app.use('/', require("./controller/restapi/router"));
```

Comment: Probably a mistake. Using it once is okay.